# Resource-Image usability for a Canvas background

Tags: c#, wpf, wpf-controls, background-image

I'll be able to program a short program where you can click on a canvas and you'll get the RGB color value for the clicked pixel.

At first i had the graphics on my own HDD with absolute paths.
Problem is, that the program will crashed on each other pc ;)

So, i had created a folder named "Recourcen" within the Project explorer.
Inserted are all the graphics i need.

If i define some images in wpf and write it as follow

```
...Source="/Resourcen/color_wheel_730.png"
```

The Image get the right source.

But if i want to use it for a canvas in source, it doesn't run without getting errors.#

```
canvas_colorpick.Background = new ImageBrush
            {
                ImageSource = new BitmapImage(new Uri(@"..\..\Resourcen\color_wheel_730.png", UriKind.Relative))
            };
```

I had tested some formattings, but nothing will work in the source code section :(
After some hours of testing i thought i must be put a question to these forum.

Hope somebody can help me with my noob question above.

Greetings from Germany!
Bjoern

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure you have set the **`BuildAction`** as **`Resource`** for added image file in your project.

Also, try using [**WPF Pack URI**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa970069(v=vs.110).aspx) to provide the uri source:

```
canvas_colorpick.Background = new ImageBrush
   {
      ImageSource = new BitmapImage(new Uri(@"pack://application:,,,/Resourcen/color_wheel_730.png"))
   };
```

***Note*** - Assuming folder Resourcen folder added in same project where XAML resides.

Comment: Fantastic! Thank you for your great answer on my problem :)  All problems with it solved. I had spend some hours in it, but don't understand the pack://... source. Have a nice weekend!